# enable/disable submit button based in input field (filled/not filled)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit, checkvalidity

what I am missing in this code, If I just want the input submit button to enable/disable/enable.. as long as I fill or unfill the input text? 
sorry I am doing my best to learn javascript...can anyone help me fix this code?

```
<form name="myform" method="post">
<input onkeyup="checkFormsValidity();" id="input_id" type="text" name="input_name" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="submit_name" value="OK" class="submit_class" id="SubmitButton"/>
</form>

<script>
var sbmtBtn = document.getElementById("SubmitButton");
sbmtBtn.disabled = true; 

function checkFormsValidity(){
var myforms = document.forms["myform"];   
    if (myforms.checkValidity()) {
        sbmtBtn.disabled = false;
    } else {
        sbmtBtn.disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1zfm6uck/

Am I missing declaring onLoad mode or something like this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkFormsValidity(){
```

needs to be change to:

```
checkFormsValidity = function(){
```

Personally I wouldn't check validity that way, but in terms of making your code work without error, that will do it.

Edit: Also add `required="required"` to the input.

Comment: okey thanks, that does the trick.
But have you noticed that if I delete/unfill the input text the submit button does not go back to the disabled mode?
How can we fix that?

Comment: Add `required="required"` to the input

Answer (score 3):

Actually - if it wasn't a `jsfiddle` example your code would work great:

```js
var sbmtBtn = document.getElementById("SubmitButton");
sbmtBtn.disabled = true; 

function checkFormsValidity(){
  var myforms = document.forms["myform"];   
  if (myforms.checkValidity()) {
    sbmtBtn.disabled = false;
  } else {
    sbmtBtn.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```css
input[type='submit']:disabled{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" method="post">
<input onkeyup="checkFormsValidity();" id="input_id" type="text" name="input_name" value="" required="required" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_name" value="OK" class="submit_class" id="SubmitButton"/>
</form>
```

The problem was the jsfiddle put your javascript code inside a clousure, so the `checkFormsValidity` function is not available in the scope of your `input`.

I added a `required="required"` to your `input` to make sure it's a required field (which will affect the `checkValidity()` of your form).

Comment: thanks, so basically I just missed adding required="required"

Comment: In your computer/server you probably missed the `required`, yeah.